# Why air sdk always changes "application id" for my app after I made release package for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I wrote applicationId in manifest for example as "com.game.supergame"
After I created release build and submit it to the google market "application id" was changed to "air.com.game.supergame"

Why it is only for Android?
Where I can read about this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

it's added to track air apps in the store.
you can check this: 
http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/opt-out-air-application-analytics.html , it explains how to remove the air. prefix in the android app id